# Why is this GeoJSON file invalid?

Tags: json, geojson

I am trying to work with a GeoJSON file that looks like so:

```
[
    {
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point", 
            "coordinates": [
                35.109876, 
                32.711323
            ]
        }, 
        "type": "Feature", 
        "properties": {
            "name": "אורנים"
        }
    },
    // ...
]
```

(the full file can be found at: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yuvadm/geolocations-il/master/cities.geojson)

This file, however, fails to render on Github, and it also fails validation through http://geojsonlint.com/ which claims that `Data was not a JSON object`. This file **does** however validate when run through a JSON linter.

Any idea why this isn't a valid GeoJSON?

Comment: Note that "Data was not a JSON object" means that the outermost JSON layer is not a JSON *object* but rather a JSON *array*.  Presumably the interfaces you're dealing with require the outermost layer to be an *object* (even though the JSON spec allows either *object* or *array*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the GeoJSON spec does support collections, they just need to be wrapped properly:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point", 
                "coordinates": [
                    35.109876, 
                    32.711323
                ]
            }, 
            "type": "Feature", 
            "properties": {
                "name": "אורנים"
            }
        },
        // ...
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As single elements of your list verifies on GeoJSONlint and the file itself is valid JSON I read the [GeoJSON spec](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html) and what I saw there is it seems not to support lists of GeoJSON objects. So it should be able to verify each single element of your list but not the list as a whole…